# How to make Table <td> and <tr> full width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't make its width `100%` and text `middle`. As I mentioned in the table, `The problem is here` this place isn't 100% width, and text isn't in center. how can I make it?

```css
   .hoverTable{
  width:100%; 
  border-collapse:collapse; 
 }
 .hoverTable td{ 
  padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
 }
 /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
 .hoverTable tr{
  background: #b8d1f3;
 }
 /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    .hoverTable tr:hover {
          background-color: #ffff99;
    }
 .hoverTable th{
  background: #b8d1f3;
 }
```

```html
<table class="hoverTable">
<tr>
 <th>The problem is here</th>
</tr>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" 
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 
    <td>Item 1A</td>
    <td>Item 1B</td>
    <td>Item 1C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" 
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 
    <td>Item 2A</td>
    <td>Item 2B</td>
    <td>Item 2C</td>
</tr>

<th class="width: 100%;">The problem is here</th>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" 
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 
   <td>Item 3A</td>
   <td>Item 3B</td>
   <td>Item 3C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" 
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 
   <td>Item 4A</td>
   <td>Item 4B</td>
   <td>Item 4C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" 
    onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 
    <td>Item 5A</td>
    <td>Item 5B</td>
    <td>Item 5C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thank you

Comment: why not just add the rule `text-align: center;` to the `td`

Comment: you have 3 columns in some rows ... use colspan=3 in a cell if you only have one cell in a row

Comment: how about `colspan=3`? As you have 3 columns, but the problem one only have 1 in that row, you need to expand it.

Answer (score 5):

can use the goodOld colspan attr:

```css
   .hoverTable{
  width:100%; 
  border-collapse:collapse; 
 }
 .hoverTable td{ 
  padding:7px; border:#4e95f4 1px solid;
 }
 /* Define the default color for all the table rows */
 .hoverTable tr{
  background: #b8d1f3;
 }
 /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
    .hoverTable tr:hover {
          background-color: #ffff99;
    }
 .hoverTable th{
  background: #b8d1f3;
 }
```

```html
<table class="hoverTable">
<tr>
 <th colspan="3">The problem is here</th>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 <td>Item 1A</td><td>Item 1B</td><td>Item 1C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 <td>Item 2A</td><td>Item 2B</td><td>Item 2C</td>
</tr>

<th colspan="3" class="width: 100%;">The problem is here</th>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 <td>Item 3A</td><td>Item 3B</td><td>Item 3C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 <td>Item 4A</td><td>Item 4B</td><td>Item 4C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
 <td>Item 5A</td><td>Item 5B</td><td>Item 5C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

you might also consider taking the line out of table structure (avoiding nesting is probably better than using colspan because you don't need to know the column number)

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 3 cols in each row, to make the `td` in the single cell row we need to use the [colspan attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-colspan), then the [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) rule can be used to center align the text

```css
.hoverTable {
  width: 100 %;
  border - collapse: collapse;
}
.hoverTable td {
  padding: 7px;
  border: #4e95f4 1px solid;
}
.hoverTable th {
  text-align: center;
}
/* Define the default color for all the table rows */

.hoverTable tr {
  background: # b8d1f3;
}
/* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */

.hoverTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ffff99;
}
.hoverTable th {
  background: #b8d1f3;
}
```

```html
<table class="hoverTable">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">The problem is here</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 1A</td>
    <td>Item 1B</td>
    <td>Item 1C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 2A</td>
    <td>Item 2B</td>
    <td>Item 2C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">The problem is here</th>
  </tr>
  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 3A</td>
    <td>Item 3B</td>
    <td>Item 3C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 4A</td>
    <td>Item 4B</td>
    <td>Item 4C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 5A</td>
    <td>Item 5B</td>
    <td>Item 5C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```